# Azure Backup Vault: UserErrorBackupUserAuthFailed on PostgreSQL database

Tags: azure, postgresql, azure-backup

I created a web application on Azure consisting of a Virtual Machine and a PostgreSQL 10 database. I want to configure the Azure "Backup vault" service to periodically perform a database backup. So, I created the "Backup vault" service and the backup policy as explained in this [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxTizWAeip0&ab_channel=MicrosoftAzure). However, at the end of the process, the validation of the selected databases fails with the following error:

- **Error code**: UserErrorBackupUserAuthFailed
- **Message**: Backup user authentication failed.
- **Recommendations**: Configure appropriate permissions for the backup user as mentioned at https://aka.ms/osstroubleshooting.
- **DetailedNonLocalisedMessage**: 28P01: password authentication failed for user "azure_backup"

After reading the "UserErrorBackupUserAuthFailed" chapter of the [above guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql), I set myself up as the Active Directory admin of the PostgreSQL database. However, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was also facing the same problem, after digging into few MSDN documentation I fixed it.

You need to run 1 script as per suggested by MSDN.
As per [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql#usererrormsimissingpermissions) they have attached one [document](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/4/d/74d689aa-909d-4d3e-9b18-f8e465a7ebf5/OSSbkpprep_automated.docx) file. Which is having proper steps to solve this issue.

Please make sure that you have installed azure-cli in your machine.

If you face any error like: **.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system**  
Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301956/6612255)